# Adding and removing the element of an Array in a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have an array like this :-

`let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

I want to remove its last element after every 20 seconds and then add it in the beginning of its own array and this process will continuous and should never stop

Comment: so is not a coding service, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function arrayCycler(arr) {
  const newArray = [...arr];
  const lastElement = newArray.pop();
  newArray.unshift(lastElement);
  return newArray;
}

let newArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; // will be changed on every 20 seconds

setInterval(() => {
 newArray = arrayCycler(newArray);
}, 20000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval` to update the list every 20 seconds.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

You can use slice to get the array without the last element.

```
arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1)
```

I'll let you put it all together

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript

```
  var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  let circularList=setInterval( function(){
  arr.unshift(arr.pop())
  console.log(arr)
  if(arr.length==0)
     clearInterval(circularList)
  },20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using an immediately-invoked function. Here it loops every second for convenience so adjust the counter from `1000` to `20000`.

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

(function loop(arr) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
  setTimeout(() => {

    // `pop` off the last element
    // and `unshift` on to the beginning
    // of the array
    arr.unshift(arr.pop());

    // Call `loop` again with the
    // updated array
    loop(arr);
  }, 1000);
}(arr));
```